# Business Logic In Application Or Database Level

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I want to determine where to write the business logic in `application level or database server level`. For example if I have simple procedure which sum the total price.What is the difference between to call the procedure with the logic to sum all of them and in application level to iterate each entity and make total sum after calling `select *`

Database level:

```
SELECT 
SUM(sod.UnitPrice) 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
```

OR

Application level:

```
foreach (var person IN context.GetAllPpl())
{
    price += person.price;
}
```

What is the best approach for performance view of point ?

Comment: As with so many questions like this: it depends...

Comment: The answer to the question actually asked (what is the best approach from performance point of view) is not "primarily opinion-based" at all.  All it takes to factually answer the question is count the number of objects serialized over the wire.  That's not opinion, that's fact.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal here is to get the sum of UnitPrice, it's much more efficient to do the summation in your SQL query. This will always select exactly one row and one column, rather than every row and every column.

```
SELECT 
SUM(sod.UnitPrice) 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
```